# How to check if exist and extract year and percentage in CSV python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file, news.csv, that contains many data. I wanted to check whether the row contains any year, and if yes,1, else 0. This also applies to percentage, if the row contains percentage, return 1, else 0. And also to extract them.

Below are my codes so far. I got errors(ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1), when i tried to extract the percentage

```
news=pd.read_csv("news.csv")
news['year']= news['STORY'].str.extract(r'(?!\()\b(\d+){1}')
news["howmanyyear"] = news["STORY"].str.count(r'(?!\()\b(\d+){1}')
news["existyear"] = news["howmany"] != 0
news["existyear"] = news["existyear"].astype(int)
news['percentage']= news['STORY'].str.extract(r'(\s100|\s\d{1})(\.\d+)+%')


news.to_csv('news.csv')
```

The code to extract the year, seemed to work but, it also extract ordinary digits, and only extract one of the years.

My CSV file sample

```
ID  STORY                                                            
1   There are a total of 2,070 people died in 2001 due to the virus                         
2   20% of people in the village have diabetes in 2007                        
3   About 70 percent of them still believe the rumor                            
4  In 2003 and 2020, the pneumonia pandemic spread in the world
```

Below are the outputs I want:

```
ID  STORY                                                            existyear  year    existpercentage  percentage
1   There are a total of 2,070 people died in 2001 due to the virus    1        2001      0              -
2   20% of people in the village have diabetes in 2007                 1        2007      1              20%
3   About 70 percent of them still believe the rumor                   0         -        1              70
4  In 2003 and 2020, the pneumonia pandemic spread in the world        1       2003,2020  0              -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating your sample dataframe:**

```
c = [1,2,3,4]
d = ["There are a total of 2,070 people died in 2001 due to the virus" , "20% of people in the village have diabetes in 2007 ",
    "About 70 percent of them still believe the rumor", "In 2003 and 2020, the pneumonia pandemic spread in the world"] 
f = ['2001', '2007', '-', '2003,2020']
g = ['-', '20%', '70', '-']
df = pd.DataFrame([c,d,f,g]).T
df.rename(columns = {0:'ID ', 1:'STORY', 2:'year', 3:'percentage'}, inplace = True)
```

---

**df:**

```
ID  STORY                                                           year    percentage
1   There are a total of 2,070 people died in 2001 due to the virus 2001    -
2   20% of people in the village have diabetes in 2007              2007    20%
3   About 70 percent of them still believe the rumor                -       70
4   In 2003 and 2020, the pneumonia pandemic spread in the world    2003,2020 -
```

---

**Code:**

```
def year_exits_or_not(row):
    if re.match(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', row):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def perc_or_not(row):
    if re.match(r'.*\d+', row):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['existyear'] = df.year.apply(year_exits_or_not)
df['existpercentage'] = df.percentage.apply(perc_or_not)
```

---

**df:**

```
ID  STORY                                                            existyear  year    existpercentage  percentage
1   There are a total of 2,070 people died in 2001 due to the virus    1        2001      0              -
2   20% of people in the village have diabetes in 2007                 1        2007      1              20%
3   About 70 percent of them still believe the rumor                   0         -        1              70
4   In 2003 and 2020, the pneumonia pandemic spread in the world       1       2003,2020  0              -
```

**Edit:**

```
df.year = df.STORY.apply(lambda row: str(re.findall(r'.*?([1-3][0-9]{3})', row))[1:-1])

df.percentage = df.STORY.apply(lambda row: str(re.findall(r"(\d+)(?:%| percent)", row))[1:-1])
```

---

**df:**

```
    ID  STORY                                                year          percentage
0   1   There are a total of 2,070 people died in 2001...   '2001'  
1   2   20% of people in the village have diabetes in ...   '2007'         '20'
2   3   About 70 percent of them still believe the rumor                   '70'
3   4   In 2003 and 2020, the pneumonia pandemic sprea...   '2003', '2020'
```

Comment: i wanted to know how i could extract the year and percentage as well, see my edited question

Comment: You should have given us the dataframe. Be always clear about what you want.

Comment: i have included the dataframe

Comment: Year one can be extracted using `re.findall(r'.*?([1-3][0-9]{3})', row)` I will edit my answer

Comment: @strawberrylatte: I have updated my answer. I think this is you want. You can modify the code as per your needs.